# Manual Addition into a Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, dictionary, binary-search-tree

I successfully created a BST that reads data from a text file and connects the nodes accordingly, albeit in an unbalanced way, however, now I am having problems with the user input.

Here is an example of what a line from the text file looks like:

```
student id1, mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, midterm mark, exam mark
```

My functions that turn this into a BST look like this:

```
def marks(tree, Data):
    global assignment1
    global assignment2
    global assignment3
    global assignment4
    global assignment5
    global midterm
    global exam
    global counter
    for students in Data[:len(Data)-2]:
        data = students.split(',')
        assignment1 += float(data[1])
        assignment2 += float(data[2])
        assignment3 += float(data[3])
        assignment4 += float(data[4])
        assignment5 += float(data[5])
        midterm     += float(data[6])
        exam        += float(data[7])
        if float(data[7]) < 32.5:
            counter+=1
        tree = add(tree, data)
    return tree

def add(tree, data):
    if tree == None:
        tree = {'data':data,'left':None, 'right':None}
        return tree
    elif data[0] < tree['data'][0]:
        tree['left'] = add(tree['left'], data)
        return tree
    elif data[0] > tree['data'][0]:
        tree['right'] = add(tree['right'], data)
        return tree
```

This produces a BST, but now I want to create a function that allows for manual addition into the BST (always adding at the leaves).

```
def manual_addition(myTree):
    new_student = {}
    student_id = input("Please enter the student id: ")
    hw1 = input("Please enter their first assignment mark: ")
    hw2 = input("Please enter their second assignment mark: ")
    hw3 = input("Please enter their third assignment mark: ")
    hw4 = input("Please enter their fourth assignment mark: ")
    hw5 = input("Please enter their fifth assignment mark: ")
    midterm = input("Please enter their midterm mark: ")
    exam = input("Please enter their final exam mark: ")
    new_student = [student_id, hw1, hw2, hw3, hw4, hw5, midterm, exam]
    myTree = add(myTree, new_student)
    return myTree
```

However, when I print my BST, if for example the id I entered was 300, it appears in the right of an id greater than 2000. It should appear at the very left of my BST, since the lowest id in the text file is 2000. What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out all I forgot to do was mention that the data types were floating point numbers, which confuses me because I'm wondering how a binary search tree was created in the first place when the comparison operators were comparing strings.